# How can I transfer files from Server-Side to Client using Sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, client-side, server-side

I'm having trouble on where to begin performing this task, I'd like some examples or input on how I should set up my server/client components to receive and send data including letting the client download images.

Here's my client-side code:

```
package V3;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Version3Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket kkSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            kkSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
            out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: taranis.");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: taranis.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String fromServer;
        String fromUser;

        while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);
            if (fromServer.equals("Bye."))
                break;

            fromUser = stdIn.readLine();
        if (fromUser != null) {
                System.out.println("Client: " + fromUser);
                out.println(fromUser);
        }
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        stdIn.close();
        kkSocket.close();
    }
}
```

And here's my server-side code:

```
package V3;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Version3Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        boolean listening = true;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        while (listening)
        new Version3ServerThread(serverSocket.accept()).start();

        serverSocket.close();

        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Accept failed.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine, outputLine;
        Version3Protocol kkp = new Version3Protocol();

        outputLine = kkp.processInput(null);
        out.println(outputLine);

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
             outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
             out.println(outputLine);
             if (outputLine.equals("Bye."))
                break;
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Thread class added for further specification:

```
package V3;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.io.FileWriter;

    public class Version3ServerThread extends Thread {
        private Socket socket = null;

        public Version3ServerThread(Socket socket) {
        super("Version3ServerThread");
        this.socket = socket;
        }

        public void run() {

        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine, outputLine;
            Version3Protocol kkp = new Version3Protocol();
            outputLine = kkp.processInput(null);
            out.println(outputLine);

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
            out.println(outputLine);
            if (outputLine.equals("Bye"))
                break;
                    if(kkp.getInteraction()){
                      Logging.writeToFile(socket.getInetAddress());
                    }
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
            socket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `Version3ServerThread`? All incoming connections are passed to it, until the flag `listening` is set false (somehow).

Comment: @Vance Maverick When a request comes in, the server accepts the connection, creates a new Version3ServerThread object to process it, hands it the socket returned from accept, and starts the thread. The Version3ServerThread object communicates to the client by reading from and writing to the socket.

Comment: Right -- my point is that you've asked us about the behavior of your program, but left out the code where the server spends most of its time.

Comment: listening is never set to false, btw. Not sure what you want to accomplish, but it rarely is a good idea trying to implement a server and a protocol yourself. HTTP is fine for most cases and HTTP server engines like Jetty will be faster anyways.

Comment: @stokkseyri: You haven't asked a specific question.  What happens when you run your code?  What fails? What part do you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

The code so far, the client-server-communication without the file-transfer ability, looks fine to me. I wanted to compile to find any errors but you didnt include Version3Protocol and Logging. If it does compile then your next step would be to open the file you want to transfer on the server with a FileInputStream and a new file for writing on the client with FileOutputStream:

> http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html
>   http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html

You can then read the file into buffer, transfer it using the socket, receive it on the client-side, and copy the buffer-contents into the FileOutputStream there.